# Laravel passport scope middleware return 401

Tags: laravel, scope, laravel-passport

I followed Laravel documentation and successfully installed Passport. Everything is working fine but when i want to protect routes by `scope` middleware i always get `401 unauthorized`.

When i change the middleware to `auth:api` everything is ok.

I checked the request headers and `Bearer` always present.

Any idea about why `auth:api` middleware works but `scope` middleware doesn't?

Answer (score 2):

Actually you would need to use both to make this work. You should leave `auth:api` for entire API group (this will verify token and find out to which user it belongs), and additionally define set `scope` (or `scopes`) middleware for routes you want to secure with specific scope. For example:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'api', 'middleware' => ['auth:api']], function () {
            Route::get('/route-for-any-scope', 'Api\YourController1@index');
            Route::get('/route-for-scope1-only', 'Api\YourController2@index')->middleware('scope:scope1');
}
```

The above assumes, you have `scope`/`scopes` middleware registered in `$routeMiddleware` as per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/passport#checking-scopes).